# Convert HEIF photo to JPEG for uploading to backend

Tags: ios, photosframework, heif

I'm maintaining an app for uploading photos from iPhone to a backend service. Currently this service doesn't support the new HEIF format, so is there any way to have the Photos framework convert the photo data to jpeg?

I use [PHImageManager.requestImageData(for:options:resultHandler:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/photos/phimagemanager/1616957-requestimagedata) to retrieve a Data object from the image which I then upload to a REST API.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

(new solution, the previous one didn't keep the EXIF information)

To get the image as a JPEG photo, with EXIF information, create a [CIImage](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coreimage/ciimage) object from the HEIF image data and use [CIContext.jpegRepresentation(of:](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coreimage/cicontext/1642214-jpegrepresentation) to get the jpeg-encoded image as a Data object

```
let imageManager = PHImageManager.default()
var photo : PHAsset
var options : PHImageRequestOptions

imageManager.requestImageData(for: photo, options: options, resultHandler: {
                imageData,dataUTI,orientation,info in
let ciImage = CIImage(data: imageData!)
if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
    data = CIContext().jpegRepresentation(of: ciImage!, colorSpace: CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB())!
    // upload image data
}
```

Comment: great solution, thanks! I was doing a huge dance of data -> extract exif -> UIImage -> UIIMageJPGRepresentation -> append exif -> save it.

Comment: Where should we pass our UIImage to this method? It's not clear

Comment: In this case you don't use UIImage at all, you can create a CIImage from a Data object and export it to a new Data object in jpeg format

Comment: awesome solution, thanks, it helped a lot!